# Evaluating a matrix element of a $3\times 3$ Hamiltonian in terms of Gell-Mann matrices

Tags: representation-theory, matrix-elements

A generic $3\times 3$ Hamiltonian can be expressed in terms of eight [Gell-Mann matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices) ($\lambda$) as
\begin{align}
{\cal H} &= h_{0} I +  H= h_{0} I + \sum_{\alpha=1}^{8} h_{\alpha} \lambda_{\alpha}, \\
{\cal H}|n \rangle &=( h_{0} + \epsilon_{n}) | n \rangle \qquad   \text{For  } n\in \{1,2,3 \},
\end{align}
where I is the identity matrix, $|n \rangle $ are eigenvectors and $\epsilon_{n}$ denote eigenvalues of $H$. This decomposition enable one to determine different qunatities, e.g., [Berry curvature](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6469), in terms of matrix elements of Gell-Mann matrices.

Using properties of $\lambda$ matrices, we can evaluate the non-diagonal matrix elements of $\langle m |[\lambda_{\alpha}, H]| n \rangle $,
\begin{align}
\lambda_{\alpha}^{mn} = 2 {\rm i} \sum_{\gamma, \beta} f_{\alpha \beta \gamma} h_{\beta} \frac{ \lambda_{\gamma}^{mn}}{\epsilon_{m} -\epsilon_{n}} =  \sum_{\gamma} {\cal F}_{\alpha \gamma}^{mn}   \lambda_{\gamma}^{mn},
\end{align}
where $f_{\alpha \beta \gamma}$ are SU(3) structure constants and we have employed $[\lambda_{\alpha}, \lambda_{\beta}] = {\rm i} \sum_{\gamma} f_{\alpha \beta \gamma}\lambda_{\gamma} $.
My question is whether it is possible to evaluate
\begin{align}
 \frac{  \lambda_{\alpha}^{mn} }{\epsilon_{m} -\epsilon_{n}} = \sum_{\gamma} {\cal K}_{\alpha \gamma}^{mn}   \lambda_{\gamma}^{mn},
\end{align}
such that $\cal K$ can expressed merely in terms of $h$ and matrix elements of $\lambda$?

Comment: Do you fully understand how that denominator entered the matrix equation? The eigenvalues are a property of the *h* s.

Comment: Did you mean in \lambda_{\alpha}^{mn}/(\epsilon_{m}-\epsilon_{n})?  These matrix elements appear in quantities constructed from position operators.

Comment: You evidently want $\epsilon_m-\epsilon_n$  in the *numerator* on the left of your last equation, not the denominator. You are asking if ${\cal F}^{mn}_{\alpha\gamma}(\epsilon_m-\epsilon_n)$ is independent of the parameter $\epsilon_m-\epsilon_n$? Of course not. That parameter is a property of *h*, as you should reassure yourself with simple examples.

Comment: I would like to have $\epsilon_{m}- \epsilon_{n}$ in the denominator, as I have presented in the question. The point, that you've also mentioned, is that I somehow should find a way to substitute $\epsilon$ with $h$ and matrix elements of $\lambda$ as diagonalizing my 3*3 matrix is not easy.

Comment: We indeed know that $\epsilon_{n} = \lambda_{\alpha}^{nn} h_{\alpha} $ but this keeps the matrix elements of $\lambda$ in the denominator which it might be problematic when they are zero.

Answer (score 0):

You might be  trapping yourself in your notation. First, appreciate that $[\lambda_\alpha,{\cal H}]= [\lambda_\alpha,  H ]$, so w.l.o.g. set $h_0=0$. Moreover, since $H|n\rangle=\epsilon_n|n\rangle$, the $\epsilon_n$s are functionals of *h*.

You are considering
$$
[\lambda_{\alpha}, H]= 2i \sum_{\beta, \gamma} f^{\alpha \beta\gamma}h_\beta \lambda_\gamma.
$$

Defining $\Lambda ^\alpha (m,n)=\langle m |\lambda_{\alpha} | n \rangle $, the matrix elements of the above linear equation are
$$
\lambda_{\alpha}(m,n) \equiv \langle m |[\lambda_{\alpha},H] | n \rangle =(\epsilon_n-\epsilon_m) \Lambda^\alpha (m,n)\\  = 2 {\rm i} \sum_{\gamma, \beta} f_{\alpha \beta \gamma} h_{\beta}   \Lambda_{\gamma}(m,n)  \equiv   \sum_{\gamma} (\epsilon_n-\epsilon_m){\cal F}_{\alpha \gamma}(mn)   \Lambda_{\gamma}(m,n).
 $$
(NB. You have interchanged *n* with *m* in your eigenvalues' expression, not clear why.)

For off diagonal elements, recalling  (m,n) are just indices never summed over, you have the eigenvalue-1 equation
$$
\Lambda_{\alpha} (m,n)  = \sum_{\gamma} {\cal F}_{\alpha \gamma} (m,n)    \Lambda_{\gamma} (m,n) .
 $$

Evidently ${\cal, F, K,...}$, etc, are all functionals of *h*, and hence the corresponding eigenvalues $\epsilon_m$.

It would be easiest for you to simply choose $h_1 =1$ and the rest vanishing, to check your expressions. E.g., $\vec \Lambda (1,-1)= (0,i,1,0,0,0,0,0)^T$, with $\epsilon_{-1}-\epsilon_{1}=-2$, hence ${\cal F}_{\alpha \gamma}(1,-1)=-i f_{\alpha  1\gamma}$, imaginary antisymmetric, etc... Recall $1=f_{ 3  1   2}=2f_{ 7 1 4}=2f_{ 5 1 6}$. So ${\cal F}_{ 23}(1,-1)=i$.  Observe the evident eigenvector with eigenvalue 1. You might as well have *found* it this way, if you did not have it!

But I still don't fully  fathom your objective. If you were interested in exponentiation  of *H*, you might well consider [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.00868).

Comment: Thank you for your response and for recommending a reference. Well, as my matrix H is given, all $h_{\alpha}$ are also fixed. My original motivation for this question was finding a way to isolate one matrix element of $\lambda_{\alpha}$ without computing the whole matrix. This was because eigenvalues of $H$ are quite complicated and I hardly can find its eigenvectors; I was looking for an alternative such that I can compute the matrix elements of $\lambda_{\alpha}$ in the eigenbasis by using a sum $h$ and matrices $\lambda_{\alpha}$ in the original space.

Comment: The basis of eigenvectors itself you are using depends on the *h* s. Moreover, Tr$\lambda_\alpha H= 2 h_\alpha$.